# How to rename the aws lambda function without changing anything in it

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Earlier my function in serverless was:

```
functions:
    fun:
        handler: file.handler
        name: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-lambda-fun
        environment: ${file(env.yml):${self:provider.stage}.lambda-fun}
        timeout : 180
        memorySize : 1024
```

I want to change fun with some meaningful name, So I changes it as:

Earlier my function in serverless was:

```
functions:
    my-fun:
        handler: file.handler
        name: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-lambda-fun
        environment: ${file(env.yml):${self:provider.stage}.lambda-fun}
        timeout : 180
        memorySize : 1024
```

Now When I deployed this function through serverless, Got the below error:

> An error occurred while provisioning your stack: my-funLogGroup
>       - /aws/lambda/lambda-fun already exists

Please help me What I can do more to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Try [removing](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/remove/) the stack first using `serverless remove` and then redeploy.

Comment: Thanks Manoj, Sorry I didn't mention this above but I have already found this solution and it's working fine. But unfortunately I can not remove serverless even I can not stop lambda function on production. I want to do this on prod without introducing any further issue.

Comment: What I tried right now was to remove the just the aliases stacks (serverless remove alias --alias=<alias_name>) and then run the name change

Comment: @Rahul, Please mention the working solution you found.

Comment: @Rahul Please mention the working solution you got

Answer (score 1):

It's not the exact same issue but this github issue gives an alternative soulution: [Cannot rename Lambda functions #108](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-aws-alias/issues/108)

I commented the function definition I wanted to rename and the resources with references to it, then `sls deploy` , uncommented and `sls deploy` again.

The problem with this is that the first deploy will delete the function so you have to take into account this down time.